# query to create a new table that consists of data and structure copied from the other table

Tags: sql, create-table

I have a table created `employee_info` and now when I am trying to write a query to create a new table with the same structure as `SOURCE TABLE(employee_info)` its giving me an error.

I have tried this:

```
create table employees -->NEW TABLE
as select * from employee_info --->SOURCE TABLE
```

Getting an error near the keyword `SELECT`.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using